# security risk of disclosing php files name

Tags: php

I am developing a web application using a laptop server **wamp**. when I inspect my page using DevTools on chrome, i can still see the name of the php files (with their extensions). is disclosing the php files name of my application risky? if yes how can I hide them?

thanks.

Comment: There is no risk in that information, though often it is indeed "hidden" for the purpose of beautification. Google for "pretty URL" and "URL rewriting".

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exposing filenames do not imply any major risks, but can have more subtle risks though.

For instance, your website cannot be hacked just by knowing filenames, but "config.php" is surely catchy once a webshell has been uploaded. You should be fine otherwise.

If you're still paranoid, as arkascha pointed in the comments [URL Rewriting](https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/) can come in handy.